# svn post-commit: updating a working copy fails

Tags: svn, post-commit

I have a post-commit hook that should update a working copy like this

```
/usr/bin/svn update /home/xxxx/htdocs/devel
```

That unfortunately fails. (subversion should run as www-data, as I'm using apache with it.)
Trying this:

```
su www-data
env - /xxxx/hooks/post-commit /xxxx/$REPO $REV
```

results in:

```
Authentication realm: <svn://xxxx:3690> weird-looking-code
Password for 'www-data':
```

I then tried to type in some accounts/passwords, but neither the system accounts (root, ...) nor the accounts in the apache user file that protects the svn repository are working.

I even tried to

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/xxxx/htdocs/devel
```

but that doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what does svn info /home/xxxx/htdocs/devel return?

Comment: Path: devel
URL: svn://xxxx/trunk
Repository Root: svn://xxxx
Repository UUID: weird code
Revision: 140
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: xxxx
Last Changed Rev: 140
Last Changed Date: 2009-10-20 17:27:06 +0200 (Tue, 20 Oct 2009)

Answer (score 0):

You should find out which user is allowed to execute the command `/usr/bin/svn update /home/xxxx/htdocs/devel` by executing it manually. After that you can use the line:

```
/usr/bin/svn update --username <xxx> /home/xxxx/htdocs/devel
```

...in your post-commit hook.